# Commenting option for each paragraph of a node body

Tags: nodes

I want to provide this option that users be able to put comment on each paragraph of an article that a user has posted in Drupal.

I have applied some changes to node.tpl.php file, like

```
$paragraphs = explode("<p>",render($content));
```

so I can render each paragraph with a for loop, like:

```
 $number=count($paragraphs);    
 for ($i=1;$i<$number;$i++)
 print render($paragraphs[$i]);
```

Now, I want to write a module to provide the commenting option for each paragraph. I will use hook_node_view function to define a new field like:

```
 $node->content['paragraphcomment']
```

which is similar to

```
   $node->content['comments']
```

but the new one I am defining is a 2 dimensional array. so after

```
   print render($paragraphs[$i]);  // in node.tpl.php
```

I can write

```
   print render($content['paragraphcommnet'].
```

But I need to know in which file `$node->content['comments']` is defined. If anybody can help me with I would really appreciate it. Also if you think my solution is wrong, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at modules that may provide similar functionality like:

1. https://drupal.org/project/annotator
2. https://drupal.org/project/annotate

Other links:

1. https://groups.drupal.org/node/72748
2. https://github.com/patrickmj/Open-Review
3. https://groups.drupal.org/node/10875

They may not solve the problem you have but they may have code solutions that can help you go down the correct track